# I sent an email to one address and received multiple read receipts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I sent an email as the title says and keep receiving read receipts from people who weren't the intended recipient.

What caused this? How do I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Perhaps the recipient had forwarded your message to multiple addresses?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException thank you for the reply. I didn't even think of that as a possibility. This seems to be what happened and I will look out for it in the future.

Comment: If the recipient forwarded this message to others, you are not supposed to receive another read receipt. Please check if you have configured any BCC settings.

Comment: @Aidan the message could be forwarded in such a way that it appears like the original message to the person it was forwarded to. Think of public mailing lists for example, where you send a message to the mailing list and it gets distributed to its subscribers. If a person manually forwards a message after reading it (perhaps what you were thinking of) then that's a completely new message that happens to have, as its content, the text of the old message, but is otherwise unrelated to the original. A mailing list, however, forwards the full message headers as well as the content.

Answer (score 0):

The address you sent the email to was the mailing address that several people receive.
For the recipients, your email looked like a regular email, so you got many read receipts.
This service provides most of e-mail services.

You cannot avoid this in the future.